# "TypeError: unsupported callable" when saving keras model using tensorlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When saving a Keras model defined like this:

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_steps_out))
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.save(path)
```

I got this following message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/inspect.py in getfullargspec(func)
   1125                                        skip_bound_arg=False,
-> 1126                                        sigcls=Signature)
   1127     except Exception as ex:

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/inspect.py in _signature_from_callable(obj, follow_wrapper_chains, skip_bound_arg, sigcls)
   2287         return _signature_from_builtin(sigcls, obj,
-> 2288                                        skip_bound_arg=skip_bound_arg)
   2289 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/inspect.py in _signature_from_builtin(cls, func, skip_bound_arg)
   2111     if not s:
-> 2112         raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
   2113 

ValueError: no signature found for builtin <tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model.save_impl.LayerCall object at 0x7f8c1f357190>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3fe80778ab16> in <module>
      3 path = Path.cwd().parent / 'models' / 'tpi'
      4 Path(path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
----> 5 model.save(str(path))

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    973     """
    974     saving.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
--> 975                       signatures, options)
    976 
    977   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    113   else:
    114     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
--> 115                           signatures, options)
    116 
    117 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options)
     72   # default learning phase placeholder.
     73   with K.learning_phase_scope(0):
---> 74     save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
     75 
     76   if not include_optimizer:

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in save(obj, export_dir, signatures, options)
    868   if signatures is None:
    869     signatures = signature_serialization.find_function_to_export(
--> 870         checkpoint_graph_view)
    871 
    872   signatures = signature_serialization.canonicalize_signatures(signatures)

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/signature_serialization.py in find_function_to_export(saveable_view)
     62   # If the user did not specify signatures, check the root object for a function
     63   # that can be made into a signature.
---> 64   functions = saveable_view.list_functions(saveable_view.root)
     65   signature = functions.get(DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_ATTR, None)
     66   if signature is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in list_functions(self, obj)
    139     if obj_functions is None:
    140       obj_functions = obj._list_functions_for_serialization(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 141           self._serialization_cache)
    142       self._functions[obj] = obj_functions
    143     return obj_functions

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache)
   2420   def _list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache):
   2421     return (self._trackable_saved_model_saver
-> 2422             .list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache))
   2423 
   2424 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/base_serialization.py in list_functions_for_serialization(self, serialization_cache)
     89         `ConcreteFunction`.
     90     """
---> 91     fns = self.functions_to_serialize(serialization_cache)
     92 
     93     # The parent AutoTrackable class saves all user-defined tf.functions, and

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in functions_to_serialize(self, serialization_cache)
     77   def functions_to_serialize(self, serialization_cache):
     78     return (self._get_serialized_attributes(
---> 79         serialization_cache).functions_to_serialize)
     80 
     81   def _get_serialized_attributes(self, serialization_cache):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes(self, serialization_cache)
     92 
     93     object_dict, function_dict = self._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
---> 94         serialization_cache)
     95 
     96     serialized_attr.set_and_validate_objects(object_dict)

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/model_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes_internal(self, serialization_cache)
     51     objects, functions = (
     52         super(ModelSavedModelSaver, self)._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
---> 53             serialization_cache))
     54     functions['_default_save_signature'] = default_signature
     55     return objects, functions

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes_internal(self, serialization_cache)
    101     """Returns dictionary of serialized attributes."""
    102     objects = save_impl.wrap_layer_objects(self.obj, serialization_cache)
--> 103     functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
    104     # Attribute validator requires that the default save signature is added to
    105     # function dict, even if the value is None.

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in wrap_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
    154   # Reset the losses of the layer and its children. The call function in each
    155   # child layer is replaced with tf.functions.
--> 156   original_fns = _replace_child_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
    157   original_losses = _reset_layer_losses(layer)
    158 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in _replace_child_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
    246       layer_fns = (
    247           child_layer._trackable_saved_model_saver._get_serialized_attributes(
--> 248               serialization_cache).functions)
    249     else:
    250       layer_fns = (

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes(self, serialization_cache)
     92 
     93     object_dict, function_dict = self._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
---> 94         serialization_cache)
     95 
     96     serialized_attr.set_and_validate_objects(object_dict)

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py in _get_serialized_attributes_internal(self, serialization_cache)
    101     """Returns dictionary of serialized attributes."""
    102     objects = save_impl.wrap_layer_objects(self.obj, serialization_cache)
--> 103     functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
    104     # Attribute validator requires that the default save signature is added to
    105     # function dict, even if the value is None.

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in wrap_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
    164   call_fn_with_losses = call_collection.add_function(
    165       _wrap_call_and_conditional_losses(layer),
--> 166       '{}_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses'.format(layer.name))
    167   call_fn = call_collection.add_function(
    168       _extract_outputs_from_fn(layer, call_fn_with_losses),

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in add_function(self, call_fn, name)
    492       # Manually add traces for layers that have keyword arguments and have
    493       # a fully defined input signature.
--> 494       self.add_trace(*self._input_signature)
    495     return fn
    496 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in add_trace(self, *args, **kwargs)
    411             fn.get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
    412 
--> 413         trace_with_training(True)
    414         trace_with_training(False)
    415       else:

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in trace_with_training(value, fn)
    409           utils.set_training_arg(value, self._training_arg_index, args, kwargs)
    410           with K.learning_phase_scope(value):
--> 411             fn.get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
    412 
    413         trace_with_training(True)

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    536     if not self.call_collection.tracing:
    537       self.call_collection.add_trace(*args, **kwargs)
--> 538     return super(LayerCall, self).get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
    539 
    540 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    774       if self._stateful_fn is None:
    775         initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 776         self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    777         self._initialize_uninitialized_variables(initializer_map)
    778 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    513         layer, inputs=inputs, build_graph=False, training=training,
    514         saving=True):
--> 515       ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
    516     _restore_layer_losses(original_losses)
    517     return ret

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in wrap_with_training_arg(*args, **kwargs)
    109         training,
    110         lambda: replace_training_and_call(True),
--> 111         lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
    112 
    113   # Create arg spec for decorated function. If 'training' is not defined in the

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     57         pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
     58   return smart_module.smart_cond(
---> 59       pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
     60 
     61 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/smart_cond.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     52   if pred_value is not None:
     53     if pred_value:
---> 54       return true_fn()
     55     else:
     56       return false_fn()

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in <lambda>()
    108     return tf_utils.smart_cond(
    109         training,
--> 110         lambda: replace_training_and_call(True),
    111         lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
    112 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in replace_training_and_call(training)
    104     def replace_training_and_call(training):
    105       set_training_arg(training, training_arg_index, args, kwargs)
--> 106       return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    107 
    108     return tf_utils.smart_cond(

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py in call_and_return_conditional_losses(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    555   layer_call = _get_layer_call_method(layer)
    556   def call_and_return_conditional_losses(inputs, *args, **kwargs):
--> 557     return layer_call(inputs, *args, **kwargs), layer.get_losses_for(inputs)
    558   return _create_call_fn_decorator(layer, call_and_return_conditional_losses)
    559 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/wrappers.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    218   def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
    219     kwargs = {}
--> 220     if generic_utils.has_arg(self.layer.call, 'training'):
    221       kwargs['training'] = training
    222 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in has_arg(fn, name, accept_all)
    302       bool, whether `fn` accepts a `name` keyword argument.
    303   """
--> 304   arg_spec = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(fn)
    305   if accept_all and arg_spec.varkw is not None:
    306     return True

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/tf_inspect.py in getfullargspec(obj)
    255     if d.decorator_argspec is not None:
    256       return _convert_maybe_argspec_to_fullargspec(d.decorator_argspec)
--> 257   return _getfullargspec(target)
    258 
    259 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/inspect.py in getfullargspec(func)
   1130         # else. So to be fully backwards compatible, we catch all
   1131         # possible exceptions here, and reraise a TypeError.
-> 1132         raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex
   1133 
   1134     args = []

TypeError: unsupported callable
```

However, when saving a regular model without a TimeDistributed layer as below, it worked fine:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)

model.save('temp', save_format='tf')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By upgrading Tensorflow to 2.1 with CUDA10 using Anaconda as below, the problem is solved.

```
conda create -n tf-gpu-cuda10 tensorflow-gpu=2.1 cudatoolkit=10
conda activate tf-gpu-cuda10
```